# After-save flow in Order of execution

Tags: visual-workflow, order-of-execution

As per the latest (Summer 20) update, salesforce introduced the after-save event for flows.

[image]

As per the order of execution
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm

Before-save flows run before "before trigger".
But the documentation doesn't mention anything on when after-save flow runs, or I'm missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you’re familiar with Apex triggers, an after-save record-triggered
> flow is similar to an Apex after trigger. In a save
> procedure,after-save record-triggered flows are executed after
> entitlement rules and before roll-up summary field updates.

[Source](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer20/release-notes/rn_forcecom_flow_fbuilder_after-save_trigger.htm)

Comment: oh, missed it from there, thanks..!